# like query on long datatype in hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

When I execute like query on oracle on number datatype , it works fine i.e

```
  select * from customer c where c.customer_number like '%400%'
```

Here customer_number is of 'number' datatype in oracle.I have to execute same query from hibernate but in my POJO this customer_number maps to a Long type. I am able to do this by HQL
i.e

```
     from Customer c where c.customerNumber like %400%
```

How can I do it with criteria query?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like('c.customerNumber', '400', MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#like%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode%29